# Trying to copy 4Go from windows XP to VISTA/7 takes ages

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-vista, file-transfer

I'm trying to move a 4Go file from a PC running Windows XP to another running Windows Vista / 7, but the transfer speed never goes beyond 1Mb/s.

Both computers were connected to a router via WiFi. I then connected them directly with a network cable, and it shows that the connection speed is 1Gb/s like shown, but nothing else changed.

[image]

I disabled the firewall on both the PCs, but nothing changed.

Are there any utilities or some hacking tricks to make things speed up?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a USB stick but your try [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the wired connection as the default connection after you hooked the computers up to ethernet? The easiest way is to temorarily disable the wireless connection. It sounds like your computers were still using wifi.

Comment: yep, I disabled it after, but it doesn't change a lot

Comment: You can trying setting up an FTP server on the machine you want to receive the files. http://filezilla-project.org/ has free server and client software

Comment: well after all, I had to wait for it almost 30 minutes, but I wonder if that's normal or not?

Comment: Depending on the transferring protocol, you're going to have communication overhead. XP uses SMB 1.0, which is not the most efficient protocol. Vista and onward use SMB 2.0, which is better. I can transfer a 3GB ISO image over my GBit ethernet using SMB 2.0 in about 90 secs at about 30-50 MB/Sec. You're also have bit to byte math in play because your connection speed is in bits, but most transfer speeds read as bytes. Read this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WiringTheHouseForAHomeNetworkPart5GigabitThroughputAndVista.aspx Ultimately, you have your file now, which is the important thing